# std::thread does not exit

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have code which acts as a sort of anti idle CPU state. On the laptop, a USB camera is attached, grabbing images, and if the CPU is allowed to enter idle states, I get lost images. Since I don't have admin rights on the system in question, I instead run a thread which just does a stupid ++ on an integer, to keep the CPU out of idle (and 1 core at 100% usage). The issue is, on the system in question, the code never exits. On my development system, the code will exit just fine, on the system where the application should run, it works fine, but never exits.

The output I get in console is

```
Setting bool to exit.
Reached join 1.
Reached join 2.
```

Thats it. The exiting does not happen, so the `join()` on the AntiIdle does not return. Why? On one system, it does, on the other, it does not.

```
bool g_ExitProgram = false;

void AntiIdle()
{
    int32_t ch = 0;
    while (!g_ExitProgram)
    {
        ch++;
    }
}

main()
{
    std::thread antiIdleThread(AntiIdle);
    while (!g_ExitProgram)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            char ch = _getch();
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 27:
                printf("Setting bool to exit.\n");
                g_ExitProgram = true; break;
            default:
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Reached join 1.\n");
    displayThread.join();
    printf("Reached join 2.\n");
    antiIdleThread.join();

    printf("Exiting code.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: note, displayThread has the exact same exit condition, just with a few sleeps() in between, waiting for the next image to arrive.

Comment: `bool g_ExitProgram = false;` -> `std::atomic<bool> g_ExitProgram{false}`

Comment: `if the CPU is allowed to enter idle states, I get lost images` Wat?

Comment: Its a USB2.0 thing. The CPU has to actively grab images from the camera, and every now and then it is in idle and forgets to grab a packet. Thus its a lost image. Can happen on some PCs with aggressive power saving features.

Comment: Would it not be better to configure your computer properly? Rather than making an application to spinlock and utterly destroy your battery?

Comment: @SergeyA Please do not provide answers in the comments section.

Comment: The "proper" configuration would mean disabling all idle states, resulting in even more CPU usage. This way its a spin only while the application is running. Its stupid, and not happening on USB3 ports, but the laptop only has USB2, and therefore I need to spin the CPU.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/616047/how-to-disable-cpu-from-entering-idle-states This is one of the most bizzare things I've heard of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a data race, because there's no synchronization at all on your global flag.

The simplest solution is to change the flag to `std::atomic_bool` - the default sequential consistency will work, and you probably don't need to optimize it in this case.

In terms of the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), `std::atomic` with either the default sequential consistency, or the more relaxed `store(memory_order_release)`/`load(memory_order_acquire)` gives you [*release-acquire ordering*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering).

Just for the sake of perfect clarity, making the flag [`volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) *does not address this problem*. It may work in Java, but it doesn't work in C++, and it never did. If you're very unlucky it will *appear* to work for long enough to get you in trouble.

Comment: How is it a race condition? No other thread can change that variable?

Comment: @SinisterMJ As soon as you have data shared by more than one thread (in this case `main` and `AntiIdle`) and one thread writes to the shared data, then you need synchronization.  Otherwise you have a data race.

Comment: @SinisterMJ The thread managed by `antiIdleThread` reads the variable. Sidenote: I've been told that data race and race condition are different things.

Comment: @SinisterMJ you have more than 1 thread accessing the same object, of which it least one thread is a writer. Here is a textbook data race.

Comment: See this discussion of [happens-before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) - between threads, you need either _synchronizes-before_ or _release/acquire_ behaviour. The latter comes for free with a `std::atomic` wrapper.

Comment: The solution works with atomic bool, but I do not understand why. One thread is only reading the variable, while the other (in this case, main), sets the variable. Why does this cause issues, since I don't even mind if the AntiIdleThread does 10 more repeats? Like, how is the variable false for the thread when it just reads it?

Comment: Because it doesn't "just read it". You have an overly simplified idea of how variables work, and an overly simplified view on how your source code is converted to a computer program

Comment: @SinisterMJ Well, you could be reading while you're writing to it so that is bad and will give you garbage.  The most common issue though is without synchronization, the compiler can assume the value will never change in the reader thread and optimize away even checking the stop condition.

Comment: Thats interesting, but why would it then work on one PC, and not the other? On my dev laptop, it worked 100% of the time. On the other, 0%.

Comment: Because that's the nature of failing to provide adequate synchronisation: the results are unpredictable. That could be down to chance, or down to different underlying implementations, or down to temperature, or down to altitude, or down to how badly you smell that day, or...

Comment: @SinisterMJ Welcome to undefined behavior.  Behavior can change from run to run or machine to machine.  It's not worth really trying to figure it out.  For the code to be correct it needs synchronization.  Consider yourself unlucky that it ever worked and move on.

Comment: If you want to understand _exactly_ why it behaves as it does, you need to disassemble the program, find out what cores your threads were scheduled to, know exactly what architecture you're running on in both cases and examine the memory layout and cache hierarchy. It's easier to write correct code, honestly.

Comment: I had other codes which were guarded by mutexes, since I knew that I had to synchronize those parts or risk issues, but this was unexpected. Its probably the optimization removing the while() conidition to be read as the thread itself could not change the value of the condition. Unexpected behaviour for sure... thanks for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to define the bool as volatile? Is it then still UB or what I think, in worst case AntiIdle will do one increment more than neccessary.

Comment: @florgeng - no, no and thrice no. Absolutely not. That isn't what volatile does. It only affects optimizations, and doesn't make any useful guarantees about inter-thread sequencing or visibility. I assume you can't see the answer making that suggestion, that was downvoted and then deleted?

Comment: @Useless no, I can't see that answer. So my colleagues and me might need to change some code.

Comment: Briefly, [_This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)